# How to avoid circles of light in some images and get rid of them once they're there?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, lens-flare

I'm getting circles of light in some of the images taken with my Canon Rebel 2Ti. I see from some explanations they are lens flare... and solution is to use a lens hood. I will try this approach. My question is two fold: How to keep from happening again and how to get rid of circles in editing applications if I have an image I really want to use but can't because of offensive circle. I have both Light Room and Photoshop.
Thanks for your reply
Elizabeth

Comment: Welcome! How could we possibly tell what the problem is without seeing it? When you have a question specific to an image or effect, please always add an example image. [Edit] your question to include one.

Comment: I believe you already have the answer to your first question. A lens hood should reduce the chance of flaring. The second question, as already mentioned, is more difficult because we don't know how big the blemish on the image is.

Comment: Flaring occurs, generally, at wider apertures, try a smaller aperture and see if the result is the same.

Comment: @DarrylGodden, take a look at [Short answers as comments: Please resist the urge](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the circles in your shots, the damage is done.

The stronger light in the ring-form has overwritten some information that you would like to see there, and just because human brains suggest that it is *still there* below the rings, it isn't. It is overwritten and gone.

What you can do, with appropriately qualified software, is manually 'heal', 'clone', or whatever else it is called in the software, those areas. That will be more or less a tedious work, and the result might look good to the unknowing observer, but in reality, you did not get the data below the light back, but replaced it by approximations. That can only work for less important areas of the shot; if it was a face that should be recognizable, you are mostly out of luck.

If the flare is not very strong, you could - instead of cloning the area from neighboring areas - selectively reduce brightness in the ring areas. This is rather difficult, as any error in lightness would be quite obvious to an observer, so you need to put a lot of effort in it. not all pixels in the flare ring have the same higher lightness, and to make it really nice, you would basically need to adjust every pixel according to the extra light it got.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I sort of had a feeling that I was going to be out of luck as far as salvaging the photo. Now I just need to try and keep it from happening again.